# Override Events in Haskell

Tags: user-interface, haskell, gtk2hs

I'm writing a haskell program with GUI. When I write the following piece of code

```
    onClicked btn $ do
           print 1

    onClicked btn $ do
           print 2
```

Pressing btn resulted in printing 1 and 2 simultaneously
How can I override the function definition such that the last definition replaces the first one and prints 2 only

Background: I'm writing a minesweeper game. When a button has a mine it explode, then I try to play again and define the same button to be cleared of mines, but pressing it explode a mine again because of the first definition.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the connection returned by `onClicked` to unregister event handlers:

```
print1Handler <- onClicked btn (print 1)
signalDisconnect print1Handler
print2Handler <- onClicked btn (print 2)
```

Also, `onClicked` is deprecated; when possible, you should use the new `on` mechanism instead. Its use is very similar:

```
print1Handler <- on buttonActivated btn (print 1)
signalDisconnect print1Handler
print2Handler <- on buttonActivated btn (print 2)
```